# Mean and Variance of an Ito Stochastic Integral

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, variance, stochastic-analysis

my question is to find the mean and variance of the following Ito Stochastic Integral:

$I_T = \int_0^T \sqrt{|W_t|}d W_t$

I know that I need to find the $\mathbb E [\int_0^T \sqrt{|W_t|}d W_t]$

But I don't know how to integrate this, I understand that:

$\int_0^T \sqrt{|W_t|}d W_t = \lim_{|\Delta|\rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{|{W_t}_{i-1}|}({W_t}_i - {W_t}_{i-1}) $

I am used to a different situation where $\sqrt{|{W_t}_{i-1}|}= {W_t}_{i-1}$ which I substantially easier because I would normally be able to just rewrite $\sqrt{|{W_t}_{i-1}|}({W_t}_i - {W_t}_{i-1})$ as $\frac{1}{2}[{W_t}_i^2 - {W_t}_{i-1}^2-({W_t}_i - {W_t}_{i-1})^2]$.

Since $\sqrt{|{W_t}_{i-1}|}$ is not equal to $ {W_t}_{i-1}$, how would I begin solving this?

Comment: Use that $M_t := \int_0^t \sqrt{|W_t|} \, dW_t$ is a martingale. In particular, $\mathbb{E}(M_t) = \mathbb{E}(M_0)=0$.

Comment: @saz So does this suggest that the mean is zero? Can I use the martingale property to also solve the variance?

Comment: For the variance, you can use Ito isometry : $Var(I_T) = \mathbb{E}[I_T^2] - \underline{\mathbb{E}[I_T]^2}_{=0} = \mathbb{E}[\int_0^T |W_s|ds]$. By Fubini, $Var(I_T) =  \int_0^T E[|W_s|]ds$.

Comment: @Sesame Okay thank you, once we have done $\mathbb E [(\int_0^T \sqrt{|W_t|}d W_t)^2]$, may I ask how we achieve $ds$?

Comment: Yes, the mean is zero. For the variance you have to use Itô's isometry.

Comment: Look at this [post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry)

Comment: Just a clarification for the OP. In general $M_t := \int_0^t X_udW_u$ is a local martingale. In this case is a martingale because $E \int_0^t |\sqrt{|W_u|}|^2du < \infty.$